# How to handle failover in case of TIBCO

Tags: jms, tibco, tibco-ems

I am struggling to setup fail over in tibco JMS provider. I know how to do this in case of ActiveMQ.

What I have tried is as follows

```
    public class TibcoJMSQueueProducer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FDPMetaCacheProducer.class);

    private static QueueConnectionFactory factory;
    private QueueConnection connection;
    private QueueSession session;

    @Inject
    private FDPTibcoConfigDAO fdpTibcoConfigDao;

    private String providerURL;

    private String userName;
    private String password;



    @PostConstruct
    public void constructProducer(){
        configure();
    }

    private void configure() {
        try {
            List<FDPTibcoConfigDTO> tibcoConfigList = fdpTibcoConfigDao.getAllTibcoConfig();
            if(!tibcoConfigList.isEmpty()){
                FDPTibcoConfigDTO fdpTibcoConfigDTO = tibcoConfigList.get(tibcoConfigList.size()-1);
                String providerURL = getProviderUrl(fdpTibcoConfigDTO);

                setProviderUrl(providerURL);
                String userName = fdpTibcoConfigDTO.getUserName();
                String password = fdpTibcoConfigDTO.getPassword();
                this.userName = userName;
                this.password=password;
                factory = new com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory(providerURL);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exitting with Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

    private void setProviderUrl(String providerURL) {
        this.providerURL = providerURL;
    }

    private String getProviderUrl(final FDPTibcoConfigDTO FDPTibcoConfigDTO) {
        return TibcoConstant.TCP_PROTOCOL + FDPTibcoConfigDTO.getIpAddress().getValue() + TibcoConstant.COLON_SEPERATOR + FDPTibcoConfigDTO.getPort();
    }

    private Object lookupQueue(String queueName) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        Object tibcoQueue = null;
        props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, TibcoConstant.TIB_JMS_INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
        props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, this.providerURL);
        props.setProperty(TibcoConstant.TIBCO_CONNECT_ATTEMPT, "20,10");
        props.setProperty(TibcoConstant.TIBCO_RECOVER_START_UP_ERROR, "true");
        props.setProperty(TibcoConstant.TIBCO_RECOVER_RECONNECT_ATTEMPT, "20,10");

        InitialContext context;
        try {
            context = new InitialContext(props);
            tibcoQueue = context.lookup(queueName);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return tibcoQueue;
    }

    public void pushIntoQueueAsync(String message,String queueName) throws JMSException {
        connection = factory.createQueueConnection(userName, password);
        connection.start();
        session = connection.createQueueSession(false, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Queue pushingQueue = (Queue)lookupQueue(queueName);
        QueueSender queueSender = session.createSender(pushingQueue);
        queueSender.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
        TextMessage sendXMLRequest = session.createTextMessage(message);
        queueSender.send(sendXMLRequest);
        LOGGER.info("Pushing Queue {0} ,Pushing Message : {1}", pushingQueue.getQueueName(), sendXMLRequest.getText());
    }

    public String pushIntoQueueSync(String message,String queueName,String replyQueueName) throws JMSException {
        connection = factory.createQueueConnection(userName, password);
        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination = (Destination)lookupQueue(queueName);
        MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(destination);

        session = connection.createQueueSession(false, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        UUID randomUUID =UUID.randomUUID();
       TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(message);
       String correlationId = randomUUID.toString();
       //Create Reply To Queue
       Destination replyDestination = (Destination)lookupQueue(queueName);
       textMessage.setJMSReplyTo(replyDestination);
       textMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(correlationId);
       String messgeSelector = "JMSCorrelationID = '" + correlationId + "'";

       MessageConsumer replyConsumer = session.createConsumer(replyDestination,messgeSelector);
       messageProducer.send(textMessage, javax.jms.DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT,   javax.jms.Message.DEFAULT_PRIORITY, 1800000);

       Message replayMessage = replyConsumer.receive();

       TextMessage replyTextMessage = (TextMessage) replayMessage;
       String replyText = replyTextMessage.getText();
       LOGGER.info("Pushing Queue {0} ,Pushing Message : {1}", queueName, message);
        return replyText;
    }

    public static QueueConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory(){
        return factory;
    }


}
```

In case of activeMQ we use 
`failover:(tcp://127.0.0.1:61616,tcp://127.0.0.1:61616)?randomize=false&amp;backup=true` url to handle failover as provider url in ActiveMQconnectionfactory constructor. I have seen somewhere to use multiple url in case of TIBCO like this
tcp://169.144.87.25:7222,tcp://127.0.0.1:7222

How I checked failover like this.

First at all I checked using single IP (`tcp://169.144.87.25:7222`) . Message is getting sent and received normally(I have not posted TibcoJMSReceiver code).

I tried with another IP(`tcp://169.144.87.25:7222`). It was working fine.

But when I tried with

> final String
>   PROVIDER_URL="tcp://169.144.87.25:7222,tcp://127.0.0.1:7222";

I started my program. But before giving input I shutdown first server. As a failover the message should be sent to other server. 
But It shows me `session  closed Exception`.

So Am I handling failover in a correct way or is there other configuration I have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Two TIBCO EMS daemons only work 'as one' if you enable fault-tolrance in both of them. Only then will they heartbeat with each other and share resources. You should have this in the remote daemon's tibemsd.conf:

```
listen                  = tcp://7222
...
ft_active               = tcp://<ip to your box>:7222
```

and this on your local box:

```
listen                  = tcp://7222
...
ft_active               = tcp://169.144.87.25:7222
```

And you don't need to create connection and session every time! One Connection and Session for many messages - 'Fault Tolerance' means it'll reconnect automatically for you. You could have an init() or connect() method you call **once** or just add it inside your configure method:

```
 private void configure() {
      try {
        ...
        connection = factory.createQueueConnection(userName, password);
        connection.start();
        session = connection.createQueueSession(false, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

Then pushIntoQueue becomes as simple as this:

```
public void pushIntoQueueAsync(String message,String queueName) throws JMSException {
    Queue pushingQueue = (Queue)lookupQueue(queueName);
    QueueSender queueSender = session.createSender(pushingQueue);
    queueSender.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
    TextMessage sendXMLRequest = session.createTextMessage(message);
    queueSender.send(sendXMLRequest);
    LOGGER.info("Pushing Queue {0} ,Pushing Message : {1}", pushingQueue.getQueueName(), sendXMLRequest.getText());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried and it works. But I have a question. before pushing any new message I have to create new  connection and create new session. It I do not create connection. It gives me exception connection is closed or If i try with same session. It gives me exception session is closed.

Comment: not sure I understand. Is your code above working for you or not ?

Comment: Let me simplify my statement. I just want to know, Is it mandatory to create new connections and new session each every time when you push message to queue when you are handling fault tolerence?

I have updated my code

Can you look pushIntoQueueSync(). I call this method every time when I push message to queue. 

How would I do session reattachment to other active server or fault active connection  to other active server?